# Wordpress functions in Buffer API

Tags: wordpress

I've used this Buffer API i want add Wordpress functions in APi arrey

```
 $buffer->go('/updates/create', array(
            'text' => 'My article title',
            'media[title]'=>  'My article title',
            'media[link]'=>  'http://domain.com',
            'profile_ids[]' => $profile
        );

example 'text' => 'get_the_title()',
```